# Rotate 2D texture XNA

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

I'm trying to rotate my shot Texture by 180 degress, but when I do the following:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(TexTiro, Position, null, Color.White, (float)(180), new Vector2(), Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

the texture appears like this: [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the rotation is in radians.

You can use `MathHelper.ToRadians()` to easily convert degrees to radians: [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.toradians.aspx)

```
spriteBatch.Draw(TexTiro, Position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(180), new Vector2(), Vector2.One, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

In XNA the unit is radians not degrees. so 180 would be (float)Math.PI